# Accessing Firestore with 2 Languages

Tags: javascript, .net, firebase, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an application to collect data with landing pages and access the database records from a crm. I would like to use javascript on the landing pages and develop the crm in .net core.

Is it possible to write to Firestore with javascript and read it in .NET Core? I can't find any useful information on this topic. Any links would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write to Firestore in any language you want that has the ability to do network access.  That's because there is a [public REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) that will work no matter what language you use to make the request.

You should also know that there is SDK support for all of the languages you see in the [quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).  It lists 13 environments.  You should be able to find the specific SDK simply by doing a web search such as "firestore javascript sdk".

Answer (score 0):

check the link below, firebase/firestore has support for both javascript and c#, which means yes you can write and read using both technologies.

[Set up your development environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment)